# Powershell: Output Redirection Issue

Tags: powershell

I am currently writing a little script/program that will identify and sort certain files in a Windows directory. I am using the ls -n command to output a list of files to later be used by grep for Windows. However, using the following command:

```
ls -n >test.txt
```

leaves off the file extensions for file names in the output file. When I use ls -n inside the Powershell console (no output redirection), the file extensions are in the output.

Does anyone know what the issue is or how to do this properly with Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
PS C:\Users\fission\Desktop\test> dir


    Directory: C:\Users\fission\Desktop\test


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        2011-06-19   3:22 PM       1250 capture.pcap
-a---        2013-09-26   5:21 PM     154205 fail.pml
-a---        2013-09-25  12:53 PM    1676383 hashfxn.exe


PS C:\Users\fission\Desktop\test> ls -n >test.txt
PS C:\Users\fission\Desktop\test> type test.txt
capture.pcap
fail.pml
hashfxn.exe
test.txt
```

As you can see, `test.txt` includes the extensions of the other files.

---

But may I make a suggestion? Piping text output to a file, then grepping it isn't very "idiomatic" in PowerShell. It's a bit counter to a central theme of PowerShell: one should pass *objects*, not text. You might consider working with the output of `Get-ChildItem` directly, eg by storing it in a variable, or piping it to `Select-Object`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, fission. I realized that it was actually a text editor that is for some reason showing the file contents incorrectly (which I have never had issues with before). I feel stupid for that one.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use aliases in scripts, because you can't depend upon them being set the same everywhere.

This will get you a listing of all files (and no directories) in the current directory, sort it alphabetically, and write it to `test.txt`.

```
Get-ChildItem |
    where-object (!$_.PSIsContainer}|
    select-object -expandproperty Name|
    sort-object | out-file test.txt
```

If you're searching for strings within those files, you can use [`select-string`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx) instead of grep, to keep it completely within PowerShell.

```
Get-ChildItem |
    where-object (!$_.PSIsContainer}|
    select-string PATTERN
```